# What was the weight of Noah's ark before and after the animals were loaded on to it?

Tags: ark-of-noah

Does anyone know what was the weight of the Ark before and after the animals were loaded on to it?

Answer (score 6):

The draft of the Ark (the depth of the vessel submerged under water) is given in scripture as being 22.5 feet (15 cubits, as recorded in Genesis 7:19-20).

From this figure, together with the dimensions of the structure, can be calculated the displacement, which is the volume of water that the vessel displaces.

The weight of this volume of displaced water can then be calculated which will be the weight of the vessel (as is known by By Archimedes' Principle).

> Archimedes' Principle - the weight of a floating object is the weight of the fluid it displaces.

All the details and calculations are shown by [Creation Concepts](http://www.creationconcepts.org/resources/ARK.pdf). They estimate a weight of :

> 47million lb or about 24 thousand tons

Note: This only gives the weight of the ark when afloat with all its contents.

Comment: Can you include the actual estimated weight in your answer? It is desirable to make the answer complete without having to click on the link, when it is short enough or can be summarized.

Comment: @disciple Edited, as required.

Comment: I upvoted our answer because it is a good one. Then I upvoted the question because it was the only reason I learned from your answer. @disciple  I hope you vote up the question as well

Comment: @Kris I agree very much with that. On the SE sites I frequent I notice often that the questioner is not given credit for raising the subject.

Comment: I have been guilty of going to the effort of answering a question but not remembering to up vote the question. Trying to go back and fix those

Comment: Only upvote questions that are actually worthy of it. Raising the subject isn't enough to make a good question.

Comment: I'm **highly** dubious  of the CC justification (the water covered the highest hill by that much) for using a 15 cubit draft.

Comment: @RonJohn  Whitcombe and Morris use the same figure in their book, The Genesis Flood, but I cannot find an online reference to that content, but here is the book ----> 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Genesis_Flood

Comment: @NigelJ why do you take TGF as -- metaphorically -- gospel?

Comment: @RonJohn I don't respect a technical publication in the same way as I respect the Gospel. But I read Morris and Whitcombe as a schoolboy of 17 (50 years ago) and was heartily convinced by their very competent, scientific argument.

Comment: @NigelJ "*I read (it) as a schoolboy of 17 (50 years ago) and was heartily convinced by their very competent, scientific argument.*"  Professing evengelical Christians trained in the field weren't impressed **at all** with the very unscientific book.  http://www.asa3.org/ASA/PSCF/1969/JASA9-69vandeFliert.html

Comment: http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/could-noahs-ark-float-theory-yes-180950385/. Additional data found here

Comment: @curiousdannii  if you find an answer worthy of an upvote do you not by default approve of the question as well?

Comment: @Kris Nope. The question can be badly written, completely lacking in research, or just very dull. There's no problem with downvoting a question and upvoting excellent answers on that question.